# CSS Tab coloring problems

Tags: html, css

```
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#nav-wrap .container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#nav-wrap .container table, #nav-wrap .container table tr, #nav-wrap .container table tr td, #nav-wrap .container table tbody {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

td#nav {
    float:right;
    border-spacing:0;
}
#navigation {
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width:946px;
    height:44px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    /* THIS IS WHERE YOU CHANGE THE MARGIN OF THE TABS */
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
}
```

So Here is where the coding is done to edit the tabs. My problem is that I need every tab to be a different color but I can't figure out what to change. I've tried making an image and uploading it (a rainbow-type image that has every color I need) but instead of overlaying it, it repeated the image in each individual tab. Is there any way I can change the independent tab colors?

```
#navigation li.wsite-nav-0 {margin-left:0;}
/* THIS IS WHERE YOU EDIT ALL OF THE TABS AND WHAT-NOT */
#navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:4px 0 4px 0;
    margin:0;
    width:130px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float: left;
    font:11px Georgia, serif;
    border-top:8px solid #939598 ;
    /* background: url(menu.png)  ; */
}
/* THIS IS WHERE THE COLORS AND WHAT-NOT IS FOR THE ACTIVE/HOVERED TABS */
#navigation ul li#active a{
    border-top:8px solid #343434 ;  
    color: #000;

}
```

This is the code for when you hover the mouse, all it does is show that you've hovering over the option by changing it's color

```
#navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-top:8px solid /*#404041 */;
    color: #666;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna have to define each element yourself. Luckily, using CSS3, you can use the [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

For example, you could try this:

```
#navigation ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    background-color: red;
}
#navigation ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: green;
}
#navigation ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And so on. There are other ways you can do it (such as apply a different class to each element, or use Javascript), but by the sounds of it this is what closest matches what you need.